# Why are my CSS files not linking to my HTML files?

Tags: html, css

I am currently facing a problem of not being able to link my CSS files to the HTML files that are located in the same folder. About a year ago, I did a project where I built a simple website using HTML and CSS. Now when I download the folder from my Google Drive and try to open the HTML file with Chrome, I see that the CSS effect is not applied. However, after going back to the folder to open and close the corresponding CSS file, when I try opening the HTML file again, then the CSS effect is shown. I have no idea why this is happening but does anyone have any idea? I have a folder called snappers and inside that folder, I have three different folders, one that stores HTML files, one that stores CSS files, and one that stores images used for the website.

Comment: I would recommend opening up the web inspector and looking for an error or failed network connection. You may be able to find information about why it's not loading. In Safari, the Console tab shows errors, and the Network / Sources tab might also show requests that fail.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the html and css to your question? It will help us see what the problem may be.

Comment: @EzekielElin Alright. I will try thanks!

Comment: @DylanLandry I don't think the code itself is causing the issue. Everything works perfectly once I open all the files one by one from the folder.

Comment: The reason viewing the actual code may be helpful would be to diagnose the actual links between your files. We could see where your hrefs point to in relation to your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your folder structure you have to go one directory up to access the css-folder:

```
"../css-folder/css-file.css"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What changes exactly do I have to make? It is actually not only the CSS files that are causing the issue, all the internal hyperlinks to other pages of the website do not work either unless I open the individual HTML files from the folder one by one and try again.